# How can I mute the system volume using WMI in AutoIt?

Tags: audio, wmi, autoit, volume

Here's the default function to mute system volume in AutoIt:

```
Send ("{VOLUME_MUTE}")
```

But how do I do this with the use of WMI?

I am not really asking for the code, just the idea or possible ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

WMI lets you explore sound devices, but doesn't let you control the system volume.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking for a way to programmatically mute the system volume, then [Wraithdu's volume UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/84834-control-vista-master-volume/) is the best method.

There are other ways, but that's the only one I've found to work consistently on all the systems I've worked with (vista+ though)

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for this, however I'm looking for a way that will work to any platform/OS in Windows though.

Comment: @KarlaMaeZ.Jaro, `SoundSetWaveVolume(0)` might work in that case, have you tried it?

Comment: @Matt, SoundSetWaveVolume(0) sets the system wave volume to 0. This controls the Wave volume, not the master volume control. A value of Zero does not set mute status.